# GTK3 OpenGL video rendering is mostly green (YUV420P)

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to render an video through OpenGL in GTK3 on linux. These Vertex and Fragment shaders were used with succes on QT. Actually all the opengl function calls are the same from working examples on Qt.

Anyone knows why? Is it possible that GLEW coordinates are different from coordinates in QT OpenGL?

The video is in YUV420P format, so that's why the fragment shader does matrix multiplication. Is it possible that my fragment coordinates are wrong?

Anyways, here's the video:

[image]

My Vertex Shader:

```
#version 130

attribute vec4 vertexIn;
attribute vec2 textureIn;
varying vec2 textureOut;
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = vertexIn;
    textureOut = textureIn;
}
```

My Fragment Shader:

```
#version 130 

varying vec2 textureOut;
uniform sampler2D tex_y;
uniform sampler2D tex_u;
uniform sampler2D tex_v;
void main(void)
{
    vec3 yuv;
    vec3 rgb;
    yuv.x = texture2D(tex_y, textureOut).r;
    yuv.y = texture2D(tex_u, textureOut).r - 0.5;
    yuv.z = texture2D(tex_v, textureOut).r - 0.5;
    rgb = mat3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, -0.39465, 2.03211,
        1.13983, -0.58060, 0.0) * yuv;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);
}
```

My rendering code:

```
static const GLfloat ver[] = {
    -1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f
};


static const GLfloat tex[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f
};

void OpenGLArea::init()
{
    std::cout << "OpenGLArea init" << std::endl;

    set_size_request(640, 360);
    Singleton::instance()->getStream("cam1").mediaStream->ffmpegDecoder->setVideoReceiver(this);
}

void OpenGLArea::receiveVideo(unsigned char **videoBuffer, int frameWidth, int frameHeight)
{
    this->frameWidth = frameWidth;
    this->frameHeight = frameHeight;
    //Before first render, datas pointer isn't even created yet
    if (!firstFrameReceived)
    {
        buffer[0] = new unsigned char[frameWidth * frameHeight];     //Y
        buffer[1] = new unsigned char[frameWidth * frameHeight / 4]; //U
        buffer[2] = new unsigned char[frameWidth * frameHeight / 4]; //V
        firstFrameReceived = true;
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(buffer[0], videoBuffer[0], frameWidth * frameHeight);
        memcpy(buffer[1], videoBuffer[1], frameWidth * frameHeight / 4);
        memcpy(buffer[2], videoBuffer[2], frameWidth * frameHeight / 4);
    }
    //glDraw();
}

void OpenGLArea::glInit()
{
    int frameWidth = 640;
    int frameHeight = 360;
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    Shader vertex_shader(ShaderType::Vertex, "vertex.shader");
    Shader fragment_shader(ShaderType::Fragment, "fragment.shader");

    program = new Program();
    program->attach_shader(vertex_shader);
    program->attach_shader(fragment_shader);
    program->link();

    glGenTextures(3, texs);//TODO: delete texture

    //Y
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    //U
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    //V
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

}

void OpenGLArea::glDraw()
{
    program->use();

    glVertexAttribPointer(A_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, ver);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(A_VER);

    glVertexAttribPointer(T_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, tex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(T_VER);

    unis[0] = glGetAttribLocation(program->get_id(), "tex_y");
    unis[1] = glGetAttribLocation(program->get_id(), "tex_u");
    unis[2] = glGetAttribLocation(program->get_id(), "tex_v");

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer[0]);
    glUniform1i(unis[0], 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer[1]);
    glUniform1i(unis[1], 1);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer[2]);
    glUniform1i(unis[2], 2);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);


}

class GLWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
  public:
    GLWindow()
    {

        vbox = new Gtk::VBox;
        drawing_area = new OpenGLArea();

        vbox->pack_start(*drawing_area, true, true);
        add(*vbox);
    }

  private:
    Gtk::Button *button;
    Gtk::VBox *vbox;
    OpenGLArea *drawing_area;
};
```

**Also, I'm only getting image updates when I resize or refocus on the screen. It's possible that I'm forgetting to call some function when the video is updated. Anyone knows which function is this?**

ps: `OpenGLArea` is subclass of `Gtk::DrawingArea`

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed that in the lines

```
unis[0] = glGetAttribLocation(program->get_id(), "tex_y");
unis[1] = glGetAttribLocation(program->get_id(), "tex_u");
unis[2] = glGetAttribLocation(program->get_id(), "tex_v");
```

`unis[i]` always have the same value: `4294967295`, so `glGetAttribLocation` isn't returning anything

Comment: `glew` deals with OGL functions, not vertices. Your "mostly green" seems an issue in the fragment shader calculations.

Comment: @Ripi2 please take a look at my update. Also, I don't understand what does it mean for glew to deal with functions not vertices. Also, this shader works well in Qt with the same gl function calls :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GLEW` is a library that is used for retrieving the function pointers to OpenGL functions. It's needed for OGL version > 1.1.

So, don't think of Glew as the culprit of your vertices issue. If you need to change the order of vertices is due to [Winding order](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling#Winding_order).

The order also may be the cause of drawing a texture upside-down.

---

`glGetAttribLocation` is used for *attributes*. In your VS these are `vertexIn` and `textureIn`.

For *uniforms* (your `tex_XXX`) you must use `glGetUniformLocation`

---

For the resizing issue, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1060039/3871028) may be useful.
In short, you must connect a *callback* for the "configure-event" and use `glViewport`

Comment: thanks, the rendering works. However, my problem is not with resizing. When the video is updated through `receiveVideo`, I think I must emit some signal to tell the widget to redraw itself. There's this signal: `bool OpenGLArea::on_draw (const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> &cr)` but I can't call it from `receiveVideo`, rigth?

Comment: `Cairo` is useless here. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22468398/3871028) about `gtk_widget_queue_draw`

Comment: I'm confused now. `gtk_widget_queue_draw(GTK_WIDGET(this));` or `gtk_widget_queue_draw((GtkWidget*)this);`will give me `Gtk-CRITICAL **: 21:49:20.686: gtk_widget_queue_draw: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed`. So I looked up and found that I'm using gtkmm which is C++ and I think `gtk_widget_queue_draw` only accepts structs. I then found that in C++ it's simply `queue_draw();`

Comment: Just a last thing: do you know why setting `unis` to integer values is so important? The line `glUniform1i(unis[2], 2);` looks like it does nothing into the render process. It looks like only the 3 lines above it do. Could you explain to me? Thank you so much!